# Doctrine queryBuilder: SQL Injection risk in addOrderBy() method?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sql-injection

I a using `Doctrine` in a `Symfony` 2.8 project and I wonder if there is any risk of SQL Injections when using the `addOrderBy()` method of the `queryBuilder`:

```
// Order options. Real code does not specify this manually, but receives 
// the options via user form input
$orderBy' = array(
    'column1' => 'ASC',
    'column2' => 'DESC',
    ...
    'columnN' => 'ASC',
);

$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
...

foreach ($orderBy as $column => $orderOption) {
     $qb->addOrderBy("e.$column", $orderOption);

     // Does not work:
     // $qb->addOrderBy("e.$column", ':orderOption')
     //  ->setParameter('orderOption', $orderOption);
     // 
     // Error: Expected end of string, got ':orderOption'"
}

// Result is something like:
...ORDER BY e0_.column1 ASC, e0_.column2 DESC...
```

The problem is, that the order options are received via user form input that could be manipulated to something like `; DROP TABLE someTable` instead of `ASC` or `DESC`.

I already tried this, but the query builder doesn't seem to accept multiple queries separated by `;`, which does not mean, that there could not be any other/better injections :-)

Of course the problem could easily be solved by filtering the received results and skip all invalid search options. But I am trying to understand, if the `addOrderBy()` method in general. **Is it save to pass any value to the method and `Doctrine` will handle the rest, or is there a potential risk?**

I wonder why the `->setParameter()` method does not work, as it would when using `->where()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer is that column names submitted by form could in fact be used for a sql injection attack.  Doctrine assumes you have properly validated column (and table) names.

The doctrine code is fairly easy to read and it's worth taking a look at for these sorts of questions:

```
public function addOrderBy($sort, $order = null)
{
    $orderBy = ($sort instanceof Expr\OrderBy) ? $sort : new Expr\OrderBy($sort, $order);

    return $this->add('orderBy', $orderBy, true);
}
```

Note that there is no value at all in using Expr in your queries.  Doctrine takes care of generating them for you.

$this->add is a bit more complicated but basically the second argument ends up being passed along with no escaping or filtering etc.

> I wonder why the ->setParameter() method does not work, as it would
>   when using ->where()

The important concept is that prepared statements only protect **values** not column or table names.

So again, it entirely up to you to filter table/column names coming from the wild.  And looking at the source can be informative.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Expr` class: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class

Or a simple function/method to return a valid value:

```
function orderOption($option, $defaultOption = 'ASC') {
    if (in_array(strtoupper($option), ['ASC', 'DESC']) {
        return $option;
    }
    return $defaultOption;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, but as explained in the question, its not as much about finding a save filter function but about if `addOrderBy()` is a risk at the first place.

Comment: So, use `Expr`.

Comment: I do not want to use `Expr` :) I want to understand if there is a risk in using `addOrderBy()`..

Comment: Is no risk since the querybuilder will create a DQL query. What can happen is raise a exception.

Comment: DQL alone is no protection against SQL Injections. Some query builder can be considered to be save, but not all. Question is, if `addOrderBy()` is save or not.

Comment: @AndreiHerford - Just out of curiosity, if your question concerns addOrderBy then why did you ignore my answer?